# Keep changes made by BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, android-activity, textview, broadcastreceiver

I'm stuck at this point:

```
 private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

            String number = bundle.getString("Time");
            GameTime.setText("" +number + " hours");

    }
};
```

In another Activity, when a Button is pressed, the MainActivity get's an int.
Whenever I open the Activity, I cannot see the GameTime TextView with the `number` variable in it.

I know that the OnReceive method works, beacause I had put a toast in it, and I could see the toast after sending the int from the other Activity.
How can I keep the changes made to the TextView while changing Activities?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One way:**

Define an interface in your activity & Implement the interface inside your activity and pass its reference to the other class and call that reference whenever you need.

Example:

a) Create an interface

```
public interface MyBroadcastListener{
 public void doSomething(String result);
}
```

b) Initialize BroadCastReceiver

```
public class TestNotifAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
private MyBroadcastListener listener;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    listener = (MyBroadcastListener)context;
    listener.doSomething("Some Result");
}
}
```

c)  Implement the interface in Activity

```
public YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyBroadcastListener{
// Your Activity code 
public void updateTheTextView(String t) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(t);
}
@Override
public void doSomething(String result){
     updateTheTextView(result);          // Calling method from Interface
}
}
```

**Another Way :**

a) Put a Receiver inside your Activity class

```
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            textView.setText(intent.getStringExtra("extra"));
    }
};
```

b) Register BroadCastReceiver

```
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver , new IntentFilter("trigger_broadcust"));
```

c) Call  sendBroadcast

```
Intent intent = new Intent("trigger_broadcust");
intent.putStringExtra("extra", "data");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```